# mysql query to calculate average times between entries in a given date range

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table that has the following columns: entryDate, entryTime, entryAmt

Some typical rows would look something like:

```
2013-01-02, 11:15:15, 30
2013-01-02, 11:52:10, 15
2013-01-02, 14:48:16, 15
2013-01-01, 10:10:11, 30
2013-01-01, 11:00:00, 15
```

etc...

Now my question is would it be possible using a MYSQL query to find an average of the difference in times for one day's worth of activity in the entryTime column? That is, for example, I would want to know what the average length of time between each entryTime for the day is (on 2013-01-02, the entryTimes are 11:15:15, 11:52:10, and 14:48:16.  I want to know the average amount of time that has elapsed between each time listed).

Comment: Yes, this is possible. [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I haven't.  I don't know where to start.  That's why I asked the question...

Comment: Please seek advice from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). This question does not fit the Q&A format. You're basically asking us to do the work for you. These types of questions should be supported with code. I would advise that you try something on your own, then once you get stuck, seek help from us.

Comment: That's not helpful Aarolama. Why would I post gibberish code if I didn't know where to start. There are people out there that are far more familiar with MySQL than myself. It was a very straightforward question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```sql
SELECT `entryDate`, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(
         CASE WHEN COUNT(`entryTime`) = 1 THEN 0 
           ELSE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(`entryTime`), MIN(`entryTime`))) / (COUNT(`entryTime`) - 1) 
         END) average
  FROM entries
 GROUP BY `entryDate`
```

Output

```
+------------+----------+
| date       | average  |
+------------+----------+
| 2013-01-01 | 00:49:49 |
| 2013-01-02 | 01:46:31 |
+------------+----------+
```